# Use of docker tomcat with external WAR

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I have been looking into best practices for tomcat on docker and how to link a WAR file.

The two approaches that have come across are:

1. Extending the base tomcat image and copying the WAR file into `/webapps`, then rebuilding the image as your own.
2. Use two containers, the first bare tomcat and the second a data container such as busybox which container the WAR file. You would then mount the busybox container on the tomcat container at `/webapps` and the WAR file would be effectively picked up.

I like the sound of the second approach, however I have been unable to successfully get this to work.

I have attempted to create a data container using busybox and then use docker compose to start the services. The WAR does not get copied and the busybox container stops immediately.

**Data Container Dockerfile:**

```
FROM busybox

RUN mkdir /webapps
COPY ./demo.war /webapps/demo.war

VOLUME ['/webapps']
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  data:
    image: <Data Container Image>

  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:8.5.4-jre8
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "678:8080"
```

The WAR file is not copied over and the busybox container exits immediately after `docker-compose up` is run.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The data container is exiting by definition, that its DNA.

You need to expose it as a volume or use

```
version: '2'
services:
  data:
    image: <Data Container Image>
    volumes:
      - webapps:/webapps
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:8.5.4-jre8
    volumes:
      - webapps:/webapps
    ports:
      - "678:8080"
volumes:
  webapps:
    driver: local
```

Also notice, i did not use volumes_from, but volumes, since volumes_from is rather deprecated with the usage of "volumes" i think introduced with docker 1.11

Hint: Adjust the mount path in the tomcat container, its probably /usr/local/tomcat/webapps